# PHP mysql - how to sum rows based on grouped datetime field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
id | date              | status |
---+-------------------+--------+
1  |2013-12-26 00:00:00|  sent  |
---+-------------------+--------+    
2  |2013-12-26 00:00:00|  sent  |
---+-------------------+--------+ 
3  |2013-12-26 00:00:00|  sent  |
---+-------------------+--------+ 
4  |2018-10-21 00:00:00|  sent  |
---+-------------------+--------+
5  |2018-10-21 00:00:00|  sent  |
---+-------------------+--------+
6  |2018-10-21 00:00:00|  sent  |
---+-------------------+--------+
```

I want to sum the 'sent' status based on the same 'date' rows, how to do that? so the result will be like:

```
id | date              | total_sent_status|
---+-------------------+------------------+
1  |2013-12-26 00:00:00|         3        |
---+-------------------+------------------+
2  |2018-10-21 00:00:00|         3        |
---+-------------------+------------------+
```

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

and the PHP part is:

```
<?php echo $stat->sent_time ?>
```

it will return: *2018-10-21 00:00:00* since it's a datetime record, I want to
get only the Date part: *2018-10-21*

is there anybody know? the PHP manual is confusing newbie like me :(

Comment: `select id,date,sum(status='sent') as total_sent_status from table_name group by date`

Comment: You welcome ! Note that selecting id in the query does not make sense and you can omit that from the selection part.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty nice query sir where clause in sum function

Comment: @ManProgrammer yes you can do conditional sum like above and pretty useful when you are summing up multiple things at the same time, for example you may have different status and you can use above way to sum up them.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty got is sir, the _sum(status='sent')_ part I just found out now

Comment: @junior if you want the date part of datetime you can use PHP datetime object or strtotime() function to do it.

Comment: Ok sir I'll give it a try ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

SELECT id,date,count(status) FROM `test` WHERE status='sent' group by date

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT id, date, SUM(id) AS total_sent_status FROM table WHERE status = 'sent' GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: Please explain how this code helps to solve the original problem. Also please format (indent) your code blocks to help readability. The goal of the answers are not only to solve the original problem, but to help further readers of this thread understand both the base problem and the solution. Code-only ansers are considered as low quality posts.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT id,date,sum(status) as total_sent_status 
FROM author where status = 'sent'       
GROUP BY date;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this query:-**

```
SELECT id, DATE(`date`) date, Count(status) as total_sent_status FROM `table` WHERE `status`='sent' GROUP BY date;
```